# Android NDK linking with CMAKE build: Undefined reference to C++ object/method

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

I had this project built perfectly using the ndk build tools in gradle but now I am trying to migrate to the CMAKE system of native builds and for the life of me I can't figure out what the issue is. I'm very new to this CMAKE system so I'm sure it's something trivial with my CMakeLists.txt file, but I can't seem to find out why I keep getting this error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\usr\AndroidStudioPs\GLDemo\app\src\main\jni\glesNative\glesContextActivity.cpp
   Error:(13) undefined reference to `GLESNative::GLESNative()'
   Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

C:\Users\usr\AndroidStudioPs\GLDemo\app\src\main\jni\glesNative\myGLRenderer.cpp
    Error:(14) undefined reference to `gGlesObject'
    Error:(17) undefined reference to `gGlesObject'
    Error:(17) undefined reference to `GLESNative::Render()'
    Error:(24) undefined reference to `gGlesObject'
    Error:(27) undefined reference to `gGlesObject'
    Error:(27) undefined reference to `GLESNative::PerformGLInits()'
    Error:(35) undefined reference to `gGlesObject'
    Error:(38) undefined reference to `gGlesObject'
    Error:(38) undefined reference to `GLESNative::SetViewport(int, int)'
    Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the project structure

[image]

And here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

#add header files path
include_directories(src/main/jni/glesNative/)

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
         GLESNative

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/jni/glesNative/glesNative.cpp)

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
         dateLib

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/jni/glesNative/dateLib.cpp)

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
         glesContextActivity

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/jni/glesNative/glesContextActivity.cpp)

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
         myGLRenderer

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/jni/glesNative/myGLRenderer.cpp)

find_library(log log)
find_library(android android)
find_library(EGL EGL)
find_library(GLESv2 GLESv2)
find_library(stdc++ stdc++)

# Links your native library against one or more other native libraries.
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   GLESNative

                   # Links the libraries to the target library.
                   ${log} ${android} ${EGL} ${GLESv2} ${stdc++} ${glesContextActivity} ${myGLRenderer})
```

I'm trying to link methods and objects from the glesNative.cpp and glesNative.h files to the myGLRenderer.cpp and glesContextActivity.cpp. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: According to the error log, undefined references are detected not in the *native* library, but in others, which you never link. (`target_link_libraries` links **only to the first** its argument.). Also, you have wrong understanding of some CMake concepts: 1. `add_library(myGLRenderer)` creates **target**, not a *variable* which can be dereferenced with `${}` notation. 2. `find_library(stdc++ stdc++)` is useless - `stdc++` library should be included by the C++ compiler automatically. Same for `android` library in Android environment. You are better start with some tutorial on CMake on Android.

Comment: @Tsyvarev hmm. I suppose you're right. I had no idea I was that far off. Better start from scratch. Thank you for the advice.